# Webform and Soft Credits

Tags: webform-civicrm, soft-credit

I have been trying to implement soft credits for memberships which are paid using a webform. I have created a webform that allows one or two parents and up to four children to create or renew a membership. Everything works just fine except that the soft credits do not contain any value.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bsOkwi64jNniQup12caNSxi1AWQx7gQ0/view?usp=sharing

In the webform I have selected all contacts in the soft credit drop down on the CiviCRM contribution page.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mnoQe5OB9vuV34Jc48AjiyvDpHUkofB-/view?usp=sharing

Is there something that I need to do to ensure that the soft credits show the relevant amount?

**Results after application of the patch**

After the patch was applied the image below shows the outcome of the patch. The soft credits now contain the total amount of the payment made by the person completing the webform for all contacts involved in the webform. I doubt that this is the intention.

In the example below the user has made a payment for four separate memberships. Two of them have a zero value and the other two have a value of $150. It is my expectation that only two soft credits should be generated and in this instance they would be for the two junior players and show a value of $150 against each contact. This would then obviously follow through onto their individual accounts.
This particular user has also paid in four instalments and I am not sure how that might affect the patch.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13c8ghcsQ8BD8CPbdYVSLFUbz8EvRzusc/view?usp=sharing

Cheers
Martin Fuggle

Answer (score 2):

we did merge a PR fairly recently re: soft credits; I tested it extensively and it is working fine - try upgrading to the latest -dev version [best to do that on a test site - though I have some production sites running -dev at the moment]. Let us know!

PR: https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm/pull/68

Awesome - one webform -> four memberships - paid for by parent -> in four installments. That soft credits PR was a first pass at that functionality. I'm not surprised not all of these situations are accounted for (yet).

Comment: Added! Please see above

Comment: Thx for that  Karin - so a while back but still only on -dev

Comment: Pls note Martin's update to his Question

Comment: I am not complaining! I am just trying to understand if the outcome of the patch was the intended result. The outcome certainly gives us much better visibility of the payment trail for which I am much appreciative.